# How to query on PouchDB

Tags: ionic-framework, nosql, pouchdb

Let's say I have documents like this in my pouchdb:

```
{
    "_id" : "685866641",
    "name" : "john",
    "age" : 56,
    "job" : "mason"
}
```

How can I query the database to return all the documents where job is mason for example? (I am using ionic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about "ionic" but I've been using "pouchdb.find.js":

https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-find

There is also "pouchdb.quick-search.js":

https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-quick-search

Answer (score 2):

As Bill said you would need a plugin for that. I use these imports once you installed pouchdb (I think I use 6.3.2):

```
// pouchdb stuff:
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import PouchDBFind from 'pouchdb-find';
```

Then you need to ensure you init this plugin in the constructor:

```
 constructor(
    public http: HttpClient, 
  ) {
    PouchDB.plugin(PouchDBFind);
  }
```

Once you init the db in normal way:

```
initdb(dbname) { this.db = new PouchDB(dbname) }
```

You can use the find query like this:

```
getDataById = (snippetId) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
          this.db.find({
              selector: {
                  _id: snippetId
              }
          }).then((res) => {
              resolve(res.docs[0]);
          }).catch((err) => { 
              reject(err);
          })
      })
  };
```